# Can Apache cxf 2.7.10 be integrated with Swagger?

Tags: web-services, cxf, swagger, swagger-ui

I have developed Restful web service using Apache CXF 2.7.10. I am trying to integrate same with Swagger (and Swagger UI). I couldn't look up an example over the internet for the same. All the examples point to recent versions of Apache CXF.

Is the integration with Apache CXF 2.7.10 version possible? If so, can anyone please point to the steps or a working example for the same?

Note: My application is regular maven based project.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Why not upgrading to CXF 3? Everything is implemented there and easy to use: http://cxf.apache.org/docs/swagger2feature.html

Should be possible to backport the stuff to 2.7.x. You would need to add swagger-jaxrs dependency and customize the ApiListingResource (https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/wiki/swagger-core-jax-rs-project-setup-1.5.x). I guess upgrading to CXF 3 would be much easier...

Comment: Let's suppose that I can't upgrade to CXF 3. How can I use swagger with CXF 2.7 ?